# Por que style retorna null?

Tags: javascript, console, log, syntax-error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
    at window.onload (main.js:7)
```

Porque o objeto load não aparece, está como null?

```js
window.onload = function() {



  load = document.createElement('div');
  load.id = 'load';
  document.getElementById('load').style.height = Math.round(window.innerHeight);
  console.log(load)

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você esta criando a `div` via javascript, esse comando

```
document.getElementById('load');
```

Só vai funcionar depois que você adicionar ela ao seu HTML. Ex.:

```js
let load = document.createElement('div');
load.innerHTML='MinhaDiv';
load.id='load';
document.body.appendChild(load);
document.getElementById('load').style.border='1px solid red';
```

Agora note o seguinte você esta criando a `div` e jogando ela para variável `load`.
No local onde você esta fazendo o `.getElementById()`, você poderia simplesmente usar a variável `load` que já esta disponível ali na quele momento.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  let load = document.createElement('div');
  load.id = 'load';
  //document.getElementById('load').style.height = Math.round(window.innerHeight);
  load.style.height = Math.round(window.innerHeight);
  console.log(load);
  
  // escrevendo algo nela
  load.innerHTML = 'Ola';
  // adicionando ao body
  document.body.appendChild( load );
}
```

> #### Referencias
>
> [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild), [createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)